# WP query based on two meta queries

Tags: wp-query

I have to select 10 posts that are received ratings greater than 3 points (in a range between 1 to 5), order by the last vote datetime.

Table **wp_posts**

| ID | post_title | post_content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sample title #1 | Nullam quis ante |
| 2 | Sample title #2 | Nullam quis ante |
| 3 | Sample title #3 | Lorem ipsum dolor |
| 4 | Sample title #4 | Lorem ipsum dolor |

Table **wp_postmeta**

| meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 1 | rating | 4 |
| 31 | 1 | last_vote | 1648730889152 |
| 40 | 2 | rating | 3 |
| 41 | 2 | last_vote | 1648730125057 |
| 50 | 3 | rating | 4 |
| 51 | 3 | last_vote | 1648821996056 |
| 60 | 4 | rating | 1 |
| 61 | 4 | last_vote | 1648835059771 |

So, i create this WP_Query (i was following [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters) and [other site](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/meta_query.html))

```
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'=> -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query'        => [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'rating_clause' => [
            'key'       => 'rating',
            'compare'   => '>',
            'value'     => 3,
            'type'      => 'NUMERIC'
        ],
        'order_clause' => [
            'key'       => 'last_vote',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ]
    ],
    'orderby'     => ['order_clause' => 'DESC', 'rating_clause' => 'DESC']
];
$posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

But in MySQL there is this error message:
"Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'mt1.meta_value' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by".

Idk if there is some problem in query args or database

Comment: have you made modifications to the WP table schema? And is your MySQL/MariaDB up to date or is it an older version? It looks like you have `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` turned on which is a problem, and not something WordPress would have turned on

Comment: a very quick search brought up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59536954/sql-mode-only-full-group-by, you shouldn't be able to generate those kinds of error message using `WP_Query` arguments

Comment: Hi Tom, no, I didn't make modifications to the WP table schema, but I have inherited this website. So, hi follow this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35882816/how-to-disable-only-full-group-by-in-mysql-or-sequelize) and seems work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to turn off `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` on your server via an SQL command

e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36568545/57482